# Open PDF file in new Tab with Angular 8 in IE edge

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

I have tried opening the file by using window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject) but it downloads the file rather then opening it in new tab directly.. is there a way we can open the file directly in a new tab without downloading it??